# run async function from web service break the program

Tags: c#, web-services, async-await, webapi

I run this async function from web service project:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static async Task<string> CreateEventsAsync(Event @event, string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(accessToken);

            var NewEvent = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events
                 .Request()
                 .AddAsync(@event);

            return NewEvent.Id;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

and the project break and return this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TaskOfString xmlns="http://api.tipulog.mkhltd.co.il/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the result

Comment: Why are you using the ancient ASMX stack? That was replaced by WCF 12 years ago. It's *completely* unsuitable for new development and I'm not sure it was even upgraded to work with Tasks

Comment: `TaskOfString` that's your `Task<string>` result. ASMX was built 10 years *before* Tasks and knows nothing about them. If you really wan to create a SOAP web service, use WCF. If you don't have a strict requirement for SOAP, create a REST API eg with Web API or use gRPC